# 2014 hat eine Ebola-Epidemie beispiellosen Ausmaßes die Nationen Westafrikas heimgesucht

Tags: dative, genitive

Recently I encountered this sentence while reading some old newspapers:

> 2014 hat eine Ebola-Epidemie beispiellosen Ausmaßes die Nationen Westafrikas heimgesucht.

The problem is that I don't understand how the phrase `beispiellosen Ausmaßes` in this sentence works, as the structure for `heimsuchen` is `jdn./etw. heimsuchen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> {2014} {hat} {eine Ebola-Epidemie beispiellosen Ausmaßes} {die Nationen Westafrikas} {heimgesucht}.

The object that's mentionend in `jdn./etw. heimsuchen` is {die Nationen Westafrikas}.

The subject of the sentence is {eine Ebola-Epidemie beispiellosen Ausmaßes}.

The attribute *beispiellosen Ausmaßes* is a genitive of quality ([Genitivus qualitatis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitiv#Genitivus_qualitatis)), it describes the noun *Ebola-Epidemie* further. The English language has the same construct with *of*:

> an Ebola epidemic *of unprecedented scale*

You could also say:

> eine Ebola-Epidemie von beispiellosem Ausmaß

Answer (score 3):

"beispiellosen Ausmaßes" is a Genitiv-Attribut. The entire subject is "eine Ebola-Epidemie beispiellosen Ausmaßes" where "beispiellosen Ausmaßes" further qualifies "eine Ebola-Epidemie". A close translation into English might be:

> An ebola epidemic of unparalleled reach struck nations in Western Africa in 2014.